# jQuery: Continue custom click event on successful ajax login

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, callback

I have a set of links (add to wishlist) with click event . The click event checks if the user is logged in (ajax request) and depending on the result the click continues. In the case the user is not logged in I have a generic jQuery UI modal dialog that the user can use to log in.

That all works well but I would like to extend the functionality to be able to continue with click of the links after the user logs in using the dialog.

ie.  CLICK ADD TO WISHLIST -> LOGGED IN ?

- YES -> CONTINUE LINK CLICK (add to wishlist)
- NO -> SHOW LOGIN DIALOG -> 
  USER  SUBMITS CREDENTIALS -> LOGGED IN?
- YES => CONTINUE LINK CLICK (add to
  wishlist)
- NO  => SHOW LOGIN ERROR

Of course I do not want to perform any postbacks, all through ajax and jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the url of the click action to the login modal and redirect after successful login.
Alternativly, if you have set it up to login via AJAX, you could store the click event target and then trigger a click event after a successful login.

Something like the following:

```
var is_logged_in = false;

$('a.add_to_wishlist').click(function(e) {
  if(is_logged_in) {
    //do stuff
  } else {
    show_modal(e.target); //pass the event target to the modal
  }
});

function show_modal(trigger) {
  //do stuff
  is_logged_in = true;

  $(trigger).trigger('click');
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hmm interesting seems this will work, I still have one question is it possible to pass the event like click, hover etc. as a parameter as well?
function show_modal(trigger, event){ $(trigger).trigger(event)}; event parameter being a callback and use the typeof event =='function' check?

Comment: Yes. You can pass through the event instead and then perhaps run a more dynamic function which will trigger the event type on the target instead.

Comment: Great will try this and get back to you. Thanks a million

Comment: Worked perfectly! Marked as answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of your server side code then you should place the **authentication + save to wish list** in the same request.

1. User clicks **add to wish list**
2. Ajax request to add page to wish list is sent to server.
3. Server check to see if user is logged in.

   1. If the **user is logged in**: save the item to the wish list and return a success response.
   2. If the user it **not logged in**: return a failed response.
   3. The ajax response callback should update the UI based on the response.

If you're not in control of your server code then you'll have to make two ajax request if the authentication request is successful.